# Biggest sum in tree

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the path with the biggest sum in a triangle, and I found this code http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Maximum_triangle_path_sum#Python. Now I'm trying to fully understand what the code does, but I can't figure out what this line of code exactly does:

```
tri.append([max(t0[i], t0[i+1]) + t for i,t in enumerate(t1)])
```

I know it appends something which is related to the max of t0[i] and t0[i+1] but I don't know what the last part means:

```
 + t for i,t in enumerate(t1)])
```

I hope somebody can help me, or translate this to a normal for-loop.
Thanks in advance

Comment: have a look at [list comprehension](http://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php)

Comment: the enumerate function loops over an iterable and returns the index (i) and the value (t) for each element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that the triangle is stored in a matrix and let n be the number of elements in last row of triangle. Let's take this triangle as an example:

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
```

Since last row has 3 elements, we will create a matrix of 3*3 and initialize the matrix to zero. Our matrix will look like following:

```
1 0 0
2 3 0
4 5 6
```

We can only move below the present element or diagonally right.So, we can start from any of the point in first row and traverse till the last row. Get the sum in all the paths and take the maximum of these paths.

```
n = 3
def f(x,y):
    if(x >= n or y >= n):
        return 0
    return max(f(x+1,y),f(x+1,y+1)) + a[x][y] #take the maximum of both the paths

a = [[0 for i in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
a[0][0] = 1
a[1][0] = 2
a[1][1] = 3
a[2][0] = 4
a[2][1] = 5
a[2][2] = 6
maximum = 0
for i in range(0,n):
    maximum = max(maximum,f(0,i)) #we can start from any of the cell in the first row
print maximum
```

We will get 10 as the maximum sum if we follow the path 1 3 6 in this case.